# Intent won't open with JavaNullPoint Exception Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

```
fun openMovieFromSearch(movieeName: String) {
    val actionArrayList = arrayListOf<String>()
    var targetMoodMoviePressed = "Action"

    val intent = Intent(this, MoviePageActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("Mood Choice", "Aggressive")
    startActivity(intent)

}
```

It returns with the error in LogCat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

The code is working perfectly in another function call, but I don't know why it doesn't work here.
Note: I'm calling the `openMovieFromSearch()` function from another activity

Comment: How are you calling it from another Activity? It’s not easy to get a reference to another Activity from an Activity in a way that would be safe and actually work reliably.

Comment: Well, it's not "another activity", it's from a dialog of a recycler view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never be referencing one activity in another directly.  I don't know how you got an instance of ActivityA in ActivityB, but I can assure you that you shouldn't do whatever it is.  You're either doing something wrong, or creating a massive memory leak.

Instead, put this function in a separate class or file, and make it take a Context as a parameter rather than using this.  Then it can be called as common code.

Comment: Actaully, I'm calling it from a recycler view dialog.
But anyway, what should I pass in the paramter of  context

Comment: If you're in onBindViewHolder, holder.rootView.getContext() will work.